# Ref vs Reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I've been working on a vue project. During a vue 3 course put on by my job it was recommended to use reactive as opposed to a bunch of ref's. I understand that you can't use primitives in reactives like

```
const count = reactive(0);
```

but it was stated that we should do

```
const state = reactive({
    count: 0
});
```

instead.

I know that this technically works and I do like the look of it rather than a bunch of primitive ref's but is this technically wrong? I can't seem to find a standard to point either way.

As far as research goes, I have looked a several blogs and articles that explain ref vs reactive so understand that part. I need to understand if this is an acceptable approach as I have not seen it discussed before.

TIA

Comment: This is an acceptable approach, but the question is based on unclear premises. Recommended by who? The actual choice between reactive and ref depends on the case and the specific traits of both, but the requirement to have state variable looks just opinionated. The question is too broad for SO in its current state

Comment: Ya sorry, I was trying to be as concrete as I could. There was a Vue.js course put on by ProTech as technical training and consulting firm. The instructor said that always using a reactive was better than using refs. There were quite a few things she just got blatantly wrong during her instructions and she kept conflating our current (We're the first Vue project for our Org) practices as best practices and our coding standards as being the correct way. She also got Options and Composition swapped multiple times. So I generally feel I need to fact check her input.

Comment: I've been working on this project for the last 5 months using Vue 3, Vuestic UI. We also utilize pinia and exclusively use Composition api for our components. I had this experience at the time of taking the course, but it advertised for  intermediate and advanced devs as well so I didnt want to turn down a free chance for more knowledge. Generally I hate doing things the improper way and want to make sure that my project is maintainable and a pleasure for future devs to make sense. I just want to make sure I do things in the most acceptable and efficient way possible.

Comment: **Previous Work:** the [Vue Style Guide](https://vuejs.org/style-guide). It doesn't seem to have an opinion on this.

Comment: At this point it's a pure matter of taste and it's incorrect to suggest that reactive is a better solution, this is the style that a single instructor/company prefers. A single `state` variable can help to migrate from options api as a direct replacement for `this` but that's all. A lot of refs can become messy as people tend to overuse them even when they aren't needed, this results in a lot of variable names with a lot of `.value` boilerplate but this doesn't mean there should be one big `state` per component.

Comment: The choice between ref an reactive is purely pragmatic IMO. Need separate values that are used together as a single "item" item? It's reactive(). Need the same thing that can be null or needs to be fully reassigned at some point? It's ref(). Need to pass some fields of item object to a composable but not the entire item? Refs via toRefs().

Comment: @SIGSTACKFAULT I didnt know this existed. I've already found a few things I'll be fixing to be in line with at least ``Essential`` and ``Strongly Recommended``!

Comment: @EstusFlask that kinda how I felt as well. It seems a lot cleaner than a bunch of refs and ``.value`` all over the place. Thank you!